# Applescript : Only run the script if specific input is entered

Tags: applescript, password

Is it possible to run an applescript ONLY if a specific input is inserted If I put in my attempts at the code i might be clearer at what Im getting at

```
set x to display dialog "What is your password?" default answer "" with hidden answer
set y to (text returned of x)


display dialog (text returned of x)
display dialog y

if (text returned of y) is 3232 then
  display dialog "Hi" buttons ["OK"]
end if
```

All the in-between stuff is just testing and making sure everything is working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're trying to check against `text returned of y`, where `y` is `text returned of x` – a **string**, not a **dialog result** so `text returned of y` won't work. Just use `y`.

Second, you need to be testing your **string** stored in `y` against another **string**, not a number. Wrap `3232` in quotes:

```
set x to display dialog "What is your password?" default answer "" with hidden answer
set y to (text returned of x)


display dialog (text returned of x)
display dialog y

if y is "3232" then
  display dialog "Hi" buttons ["OK"]
end if
```